# Get value from dynamic table mysql php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I create a table with dynamic data from mysql. He seems to : 
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DjLy.png)

When I click on the delete button from the second row, and make an alert js with the value of id, he save the id from the first row and not in the row where I cliqued.

My Views :

```js
$('.Btrash').click(function() {

    //var id_stream = $('#id_stream').val();
    var id_stream = $('#id_stream').attr('value');
    var id_compte = $('#id_compte').val();

    alert(id_stream);
});
```

```html
<div class="row" id="Tstream">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-list">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Feeds</th>
                  <th>Data request</th>
                  <th>Begin Stream</th>
                  <th>End Stream</th>
                  <th><em class="fa fa-cog"></em></th>
                  <th>Status</th>
                  <th>Access to Data</th>
                </tr> 
            </thead>
            <tbody >
                <?php foreach ($aAllRequestByIdUser as $aRequestByIdUser) : ?>
                <tr>
                  <td class="vert-align">
                    <input type="hidden" id="id_compte" value="<?= $iIdCompte ?>">
                    <input type="text" id="id_stream" value="<?= $aRequestByIdUser['id_Stream'] ?>">
                ...
```

My alert always show 74.
Can you help me to find a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First let me explain a bit about jquery selectors. This code of yours

```
var id_stream = $('#id_stream').attr('value');
```

selects all the items with the id of #id_stream, and returns the first value.

If you want to get the ID of the row clicked, then you should select the row first. But since you haven't shared the rest of your code, i can only assume the rest. There are several ways of doing so, and this is one of them.

1 ) Get the parent of $(this) >

2 ) Then get the first sibling of it

3 ) Finally find input and get val().

Or you can do it by Jquery's closest function. But as i said, first i need to see  the rest of your code.